# Why PHP explode always add 'newline' at the end of each array?

Tags: php

I want to explode '\n' in a string but php add it again.

here's my code:

```
$str = "MyText1
MyText2
MyText3";

//convert to array
$arr = explode("\n", $str); //Why PHP adding '\n' again here??

//prepare the var
$new_str = "";

//combine to string again
foreach( $arr as $value ) {
    $new_str .= "prefix-" . $value . "-suffix ";
}

echo $new_str;
```

the result is:

```
prefix-MyText1
-suffix prefix-MyText2
-suffix prefix-MyText3-suffix
```

I want the result to be:

```
prefix-MyText1-suffix prefix-MyText2-suffix prefix-MyText3-suffix
```

I found the problem. it works on linux, it wont work on windows. 
linux uses "\n", windows uses "\r\n"

Comment: Works for me: https://3v4l.org/DOEer perhaps your string also has `\r` in it and you need to explode on `"\r\n"` instead?

Comment: Yup, probably `\r\n`. Could also just `$new_str .= "prefix-" . trim($value) . "-suffix ";`